# Как загрузить картинку в WPF?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

Уже сколько мучаюсь с этими картинками. Никак не могу понять почему мне VS не хочет отображать их в формах?

Я могу указать полный путь картинок, но если, например, другой пользователь скачает - у него не будут они же отображаться.

Возможно, я не так как-то указываю пути?)

Буду благодарен любой помощи!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, как и в ответе ниже, такая формулировка является правильной. Ещё совет лично от меня - когда указываете элемент, где есть свойство в котором должен быть путь к файлу, то лучше задавайте его значение через окно свойств. Таким образом, вам сразу будет предложен список всех допустимых значений и они 100% будут правильные.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй сделать что-то подобное:

```
<Image Source="/ProjectName;component/Resource/Image/imageName.jpg"/>
```